# Asymptotic Bounding | If f = 2^n and g = (2^n+1), how does f = Θ(g)?

Tags: algorithm, performance, big-o, complexity-theory

We are asked to indicate whether f = O(g), or f = Ω(g), or both (in which case f = Θ(g)).

To solve the big O, I found it easy by simply providing constant C = 1 in which case 2^n <= 1(2^n+1).

I was under the impression that to solve the Ω would be impossible since there is no C in which 2^n >= C(2^n+1).

Upon looking into the solutions to check my work, I found that f = Θ(g). How could this be with this problem? What constant C could satisfy this?

Comment: Hint -- you only need to find constants C and k such that 2^n >= C(2^n + 1) for all n > k...

Answer (score 1):

What is the problem if `C = 0.1` as an example? Also, you can show the `Theta` notation by the limit of these two functions such that `lim(f(n)/g(n))` when `n` goes to `\infty` is equal 1. It means we have `f(n) = \Theta(g(n))`.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell whether g(n) is 2^(n+1) or (2^n)+1. In either case, f(n) is Theta(g(n)).

Assume g(n) = 2^(n+1). We can rewrite this using laws of exponents as (2^n)(2^1) which is the same thing as 2*(2^n). Now we may simply choose c = 1/2 and then f(n) = c * g(n). Because there exists a c for which the functions are simply equal, immediately f(n) = Theta(g(n)).

Assume g(n) = (2^n) + 1. Since f(n) < g(n) we immediately have f(n) = O(g(n)). All we need to show is that f(n) >= c * g(n). If we choose c = 1/2 we need to find n0 such that 2^n0 >= 1/2 2^n0 + 1/2. We can guess n0 = 1 and we find that this works; 2^1 >= 1/2 2^1 + 1/2. Because f(n) also grows faster than (1/2)2^n + 1/2, we are done.

Comment: Awesome thanks! I was under the impression C > 1 but this makes a lot more sense. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexRodriguez I think the definition requires c > 0. Otherwise, you're right, if c > 1 then f(n) is not even Omega(f(n))!